# Change the content of the text while the Game is running - Python Arcade 2.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-rendering, arcade

I'm looking for a way to change the rendered text while the game is running.

I found someone who says that simply change the text variable would work.

So I try this:

```
import arcade

WINDOW = {"width":800, "height": 600, "title": ""}

class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    """
    Main application class.
    """

    def __init__(self):

        # Call the parent class and set up the window
        super().__init__(WINDOW['width'], WINDOW['height'], WINDOW['title'])

        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.csscolor.CORNFLOWER_BLUE)

    def setup(self):
        """ Set up the game here. Call this function to restart the game. """
        pass

    def on_draw(self):
        """ Render the screen. """

        arcade.start_render()
        # Code to draw the screen goes here

        self.text = "Hello world!"
        arcade.draw_text(self.text, WINDOW['width'] / 3 + (WINDOW['width'] / 3 / 3) - 20, WINDOW['height'] / 2, arcade.csscolor.WHITE, 18)
    
    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, key_modifiers):
        print("Clicked!")
        self.text = "Clicked!"

def main():
    """ Main method """
    window = MyGame()
    window.setup()
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But still, The text didn't change but It can detect clicks.

Comment: `on_draw()` sets `self.text` to `"Hello world!"`, so any changes you make in `on_mouse_release()` are discarded.

Comment: as @PranavHosangadi already said - you shouldn't put `self.text = "Hello world!"` inside `on_draw()` but rather in `__init__`. This way it will be set `"Hello world!"` only at start. And later button will change it to `"Clicked!"`. You have to remeber that `arcade.run()` runs loop which executes `on_draw()` in every loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arcade.run()` runs loop which executes `on_draw()` in this loop. If code runs with speed `25 FPS` (Frames Per Second) then it executes `on_draw()` 25 times in every second. So when you click mouse then `on_mouse_release()` changes text to `"Clicked!"` and later `on_draw()` changes it back to `"Hello world!"` and finally it displays `"Hello world!"`

You should use `self.text = "Hello world!"` in `__init__()` or (better) in `setup()` to set it only once.

```
import arcade

WINDOW = {"width":800, "height": 600, "title": ""}

class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    """
    Main application class.
    """

    def __init__(self):

        # Call the parent class and set up the window
        super().__init__(WINDOW['width'], WINDOW['height'], WINDOW['title'])

        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.csscolor.CORNFLOWER_BLUE)

    def setup(self):
        """ Set up the game here. Call this function to restart the game. """
        
        self.text = "Hello world!"

    def on_draw(self):
        """ Render the screen. """

        arcade.start_render()
        # Code to draw the screen goes here

        arcade.draw_text(self.text, WINDOW['width'] / 3 + (WINDOW['width'] / 3 / 3) - 20, WINDOW['height'] / 2, arcade.csscolor.WHITE, 18)
    
    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, key_modifiers):
        print("Clicked!")
        self.text = "Clicked!"

def main():
    """ Main method """
    window = MyGame()
    window.setup()
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short example of changing text on mouse click:

```
import arcade

class Game(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(400, 300)
        self.text = 'Waiting for click!'

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        arcade.draw_text(self.text, 200, 150, arcade.color.RED, 18, anchor_x='center')

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, key_modifiers):
        self.text = 'Clicked!'

Game()
arcade.run()
```

Output:

[image]